# VB6 limit textbox input to numbers in the range from 1900 to current date?

Tags: vb6

How limit textbox input to numbers in the range from 1900 to current date?

```
Private Sub txtYear_Change()
    If Not IsNumeric(txtYear.Text) Then
        txtYear.Text = ""
    ElseIf txtYear.Text < 1900 Or txtYear.Text > Year(Date) Then
        txtYear.Text = ""
    End If
Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to place that code in your `txtYear_Validate()` event instead of the change event.  Change will get triggered with each keystroke, so it will almost always immediately fail.  Do not validate the entry until it's done, in the validate event.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bill!

Answer (score 2):

As explained in [Bill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50397512/4934172), you should use the `Validate` event.

I just would like to add that your code still has a flaw, that is, it will allow users to enter decimal numbers (e.g., 1900.10). In order to avoid that, you can add another condition:

```
Private Sub txtYear_Validate(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not IsNumeric(txtYear.Text) Then
        txtYear.Text = ""
    ElseIf txtYear.Text < 1900 Or txtYear.Text > Year(Date) Then
        txtYear.Text = ""
    ElseIf Fix(txtYear.Text) <> txtYear.Text Then   ' Choose one:
        txtYear.Text = Fix(txtYear.Text)            ' - Replace it with the integer part.
        'txtYear.Text = ""                          ' - Clear the text.
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Good points.  To further elaborate, it might also be best to set Cancel to True upon invalid entry so that the text control retains focus (for corrections) and also to make sure that a Cancel button, if on the form, has its `CausesValidation` property set to false so that the user can cancel without a valid entry.

Comment: @BillHileman I agree. I just didn't want to change the OP's logic, but of course, setting the `Cancel` to True is a better visual indication.